# Using u2-net for background removal

Tags: python

I am trying to build a background removal tool for a specific use case and therefore want to finetune a u2net model for the same. So how can I finetune the model on my own dataset ?. Also does u2-net return a mask and then we have to subtract original image from the mask or u2-net directly returns the image with background removed (@azal)

I am trying to use the pre-trained model but is not working.